# Creating an Outlook appointment 30 days before a specific date

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have some code set up to create an Outlook appointment, though I'm trying to set the start as 30 days before whatever date is in the cell in column G (i, 7)

Is there any way to do this, or would I need to just add an additional column in Excel with this date in?

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text 'ignore case sensitivity when comparing strings

Sub EventsReminders()

    Dim OL As Outlook.Application, ES As Worksheet, _
    r As Long, i As Long, wb As ThisWorkbook

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ES = wb.Sheets("Events")
    Set OL = New Outlook.Application

    r = ES.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 8 To r
        With ES.Cells(i, 2)
            If .Value = "Yes" And ES.Cells(i, 3) <> "Yes" Then
                ES.Cells(i, 3) = "Yes"
                With OL.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
                    .Subject = "Raise works order"
                    .Start = ES.Cells(i, 7) + TimeValue("09:00:00")
                    .ReminderSet = True
                    .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60
                    .Body = ES.Cells(i, 5).Value + "_" + ES.Cells(i, 9).Value
                    .Save
                End With
            End If
        End With
    Next i

    Set OL = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set ES = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming column G contains an actual date, rather than text representing a date, try:

```
.Start = ES.Cells(i, 7) - 30 + TimeValue("09:00:00")
```